# How to make a transition effect for 3d rotation on canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, live-wallpaper

I have sequence of images and want to create a transition effect as part of LiveWallpaper animation - something like to 3d rotation on Canvas (without OpenGL ES).

The code snippet is:

```
case 15: {/* Vertical rotation left*/
        canvas.drawBitmap(mPreviousBitmap, 0, 0, myPaint);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        Camera mCamera = new Camera();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        mCamera.save();
        for (int i = 0; i > -90;) {
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                mCamera.rotateY(-5);
                mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);
                //dss is Device Screen Size structure where the relevant parameters stored
                matrix.preTranslate(-dss.getWidth() / 2, -dss.getHeight() / 2);
                matrix.postTranslate(dss.getWidth() / 2, dss.getHeight() / 2);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mPreviousBitmap, matrix, myPaint);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                i -= 5;
        }
        mCamera.rotateY(180);
        mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);
        for (int i = 0; i > -90;) {
                canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                mCamera.rotateY(-5);
                mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);
                matrix.preTranslate(-dss.getWidth() / 2, -dss.getHeight() / 2);
                matrix.postTranslate(dss.getWidth() / 2, dss.getHeight() / 2);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, matrix, myPaint);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                i -= 5;
        }
        mCamera.restore();
        mLastDrawTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        break;
}
```

I tested it with 11 different devices

```
Asus Transformer TF700T, Samsung Galaxy S4 I9500, Samsung I9082, LG p715, HTC Desire SV T326e, Sony Xperia Z1 C6902, Huawei Ascend Y511-U30, HTC Sensation XL x315e, HTC Desire 300, Fly IQ431 and Motorola Moto G.
```

This code works fine everywhere except my tablet `Asus Transformer TF700T`. With my tablet there being observed an abnormal behaviour: at the moment between the first image is going off and the next image appearing, I see the following state:
http://i-fotki.info/16/842cc7c2d59483650edfd5de48c6a3464e1a97174989084.jpg.html

But with other devices my images are changed fluently.

So what is incorrect in my code and what I should change?

Comment: It sounds like your Asus device has broken OpenGL ES drivers.  Does it work on the AVD emulation?

Comment: Yes, it works properly with different AVDs too.

Comment: So is there any method to test OpenGL ES drivers if it is the reason of my problem?

Comment: There are conformance tests available from Khronos.org, but the GPU vendor for the Asus device may already know about the problem.  Your testing is good evidence of the problem.  Ask them for a driver update.